# How do I get Drupal to preference one of a module's .tpls over another?

Tags: 7, theming

I have modified a Global module so that it has a 2nd .tpl file. The original .tpl file is for sites using Zurb Foundation 5, the newer one I created is for sites using Zurb Foundation 6. Because this is a global module, these files exist in the same directory.

I've named the newer .tpl inline with what Theme Debug suggests (`image_resp_item--f6.tpl.php`).

Now, I've just got to tell the site that when it's using Foundation 6 to preference the .tpl named `image_resp_item--f6.tpl.php`.

However, I'm completely lost at where to start with this. Is this something I set up on the module's .module file? Or something I set up on each sites template.php file? Is there a hook I can use?

Sorry its kinda vague - been dumped in the deep end here - any advice is appreciated.

Comment: what makes your site using F6 ?

Comment: @rémy someone else's module I think

Comment: I mean - what defines the use of Foundation 5 or 6 ?

Answer (score 0):

Update the modules weight in the DB.

This code is for a custom module, when enabled:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_enable()
 */
function YOUR_MODULE_enable() {
    db_update('system')
    ->fields(array('weight' => 1))
    ->condition('type', 'module')
    ->condition('name', 'YOUR_MODULE')
    ->execute();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't think this is what I'm after. The module works fine, I just want it to preference one of 2 .tpls contained within it.

Comment: true - it's more about non theme hook_s. but maybe a simple workaround ..